# iOS8 Swift UISearchController hides navigationbar

Tags: swift, ios8, header, navigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I implemented a search function for an UITableViewController like this:

```
    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
        return controller
    })()
```

The problem I've been experiencing is that if I click on it, my navigation bar and my navigationcontrollers header disappear.
Is there a solution to stop this behaviour (in swift)?

Not clicked:

[image: Not clicked]

Clicked:

[image: Clicked]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The UISearchController has a property called `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation`, maybe that can help you.

EDIT: Just tried it myself and it works, just add this line:

```
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

Comment: What if just a UISearchBar is used instead of UISearchController?