# iOS 8 UISearchController's search bar is shifting down, If I click search bar

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uisearchcontroller

[iOS8 Swift UISearchController hides navigationbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727701/ios8-swift-uisearchcontroller-hides-navigationbar)

I am facing same problem as in above link. So I have added following line.

```
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
```

But now UISearchController's search bar is shifting down and some blank space is created on search bar's place. If I click cancel button, then search bar is restored to original position.

please help me to fix this issue in iOS 8 using objective-C.

Comment: Are you using UITableViewController..??

Comment: @Zahid No. If I click cancel button, then search bar is restored to original position.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason (I believe this is a bug), UISearchController can place the search bar incorrectly on presentation if its frame coordinates are something other than (0,0).

To work around this, create a UIView where you want the UISearchBar to be and add the UISearchBar as a subview.

You might also be running into this bug: http://openradar.appspot.com/20942583